# Continuously increasing counter with long press React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have a button next to a `TextInput` that increases its counter when pressed.

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {this.increaseAmount(step, rowID)}}>
      <View style={styles.amountPlusButtonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.amountButtonText}>+</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

It currently increases by 1 each time I tap the button. What I want to achieve is to keep increasing the counter for as long as the user is pressing it.

I have tried to use `setInterval()` but I don't know exactly when to stop it nor if it's the right approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work using the `Animated` API. A reference I used (besides the official documentation) was http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-press-and-hold-button-actions/

```
   var ACTION_TIMER = 3000;
   var listenerActive = true;

   getInitialState(){
     return{
       pressAction: new Animated.Value(0),
       value: 0,
     };
   },
   componentWillMount: function() {
     this.state.pressAction.addListener((v) => this.setState({value: v.value}));
   },
   handlePressIn: function() {
     if(!listenerActive) {
       this.state.pressAction.addListener((v) => this.setValueAndChangeAmount(v.value));
       listenerActive = true;
     }
     Animated.timing(this.state.pressAction, {
         duration: ACTION_TIMER,
         toValue: 67,
     }).start();
   },
   handlePressOut: function() {
     this.state.pressAction.removeAllListeners();
     this.setState({pressAction: new Animated.Value(Math.ceil(this.state.value))});
     listenerActive = false;
   },
```

I used 3000ms and Math.ceil to maintain the same behavior as `onPress` since it cannot be used alongside `onPressIn`and `onPressOut`.

Removing the listener in `handlePressOut` stops the counter. Setting a new `pressAction` with `this.state.value` resets the value to the one the counter stopped at.

Answer (score 5):

I think to use `setInterval` is a good solution.
Call `setInterval` on [onPressIn](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onpressin) and `clearInterval` on [onPressOut](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onpressout).

Comment: This worked for me after storing setInterval in a variable and passing that variable to clearInterval. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp